# DialogAPI with Angular 2 : Diasplay my angular 2 component inside dialog using displayDialogAsync

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing, office-js

I am new to Angular 2 and office js. I read about displayDialogAsync and created one sample.

My working sample display html page right now but i want to display angular 2 component inside office js dialog and then try to redirect it to different domains.

HTML Page : Waiting.html  ( Just for wait 2 seconds )

app.Component.html  :::

```
<div>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
    <br /> Testing...
    <div class="ms-Grid">
        <div class="ms-Grid-row">
            <div class="ms-Grid-col">
                <input type="button" value="OpenDialog" (click)="openDialog()" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Component : AppComponent

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { WordService } from './office/word.service';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, NavigationEnd, RouterStateSnapshot, Event, UrlSerializer } from '@angular/router';
import { Location } from '@angular/common'

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'addin',
    templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
    providers: [WordService]
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    title: string = 'Angular 2 Excel Add-in';
    private newURL: string;
    constructor(private wordService: WordService, private _router: Router, private _activatedroute: ActivatedRoute,
        private urlSerializer: UrlSerializer,
        private location: Location) {}
    ngOnInit() { }

    openDialog() {

        this.newURL = location.protocol + '//' + location.hostname + (location.port ? ':' + location.port : '') + "/Waiting.html";
        Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(this.newURL, { height: 50, width: 50 });
        //Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(this._router.navigate(['login/test']), { height: 20, width: 20 });        
    }
}
```

Expected Result :

Display any component inside dialog and then redirect to customdomin and get response from customdomain and pass it to our office add-ins.

Please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While you're waiting for a better answer, take a look at the last section of this article [Best practices for using the Office Dialog API in an SPA](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/dialog-best-practices#best-practices-for-using-the-office-dialog-api-in-an-spas) which is about using the dialog in single-page add-ins.